# Búsqueda por Similares en Hojas de Cálculo al estilo SQL

Tags: excel, google-hoja-de-cálculo, sql, procesamiento-de-texto

En las bases de datos SQL nos conseguimos que podemos hacer consultas al estilo de

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO LIKE '%CION'
```

Y nos arrojaría resultados que terminarán en "CION" sin importar que tenga delante, ¿correcto?

- CANCION
- ORACION
- X CION
- POCION

Y sigue y sigue...

Está función de "%" o ”_" en algunos programas para buscar cadena de texto similares que empiecen, terminen o varíen en carácter.

¿Es posible en Hojas de Cálculo Como Excel, Google Sheets y otras?

Comment: ¿Desde dónde quieres realizar la búsqueda? Si es dentro de Excel [tienes funciones](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/buscar-funci%C3%B3n-buscar-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) como `BUSCAR` o `BUSCARV`

Comment: Entiendo que te refieres a caracteres comodin (los *Wildcard*). En Excel, por ejemplo, contar cuantas celdas acaban en el texto `CION` sería `*CION`. Se utiliza el asterisco como comodín. Si pones `CION*` es que **empiece** por CION, y si pones `*CION*` es que **contenga** el fragmento CION. No sé si eso responde a tu pregunta.

Comment: @RogerTorné me gustaría saber si es posible con la opción de buscar de predeterminada, es decir sin colocar funciones en las celdas, si no que simplemente se abra el menú de búsqueda y se coloquen estos caracteres comodín como les llaman

Comment: No, eso no es posible, la búsqueda, desde Buscar, es una búsqueda simple, aunque permite buscar fragmentos de una palabra como si hicieras *CION*